# About the expected transitions in Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, markov-process

The problem is here:
[image]

**The given answer is here:**

K = $2+ X_1 + X_2$, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential random variables with parameters $2/3$ and $3/5$.
$$ E[K] = 2=2+1/p_1 +1/p_2 = 31/6 $$
$$var(K)= 1 −\frac{1-p_1}{p_1^2}- \frac{1-p_2}{p_2^2} = 67/36 $$

I am confused.
1. The Markov chain is discrete. The exp. distribution is applied in continuous case. I think geo. distribution is better.
2. Why is  exp. distribution valid?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: They mean *geometric*, which is sort of the discrete analogue of exponential. I can understand how the typo would happen: the transition times in a *continuous time* Markov chain are exponentially distributed.

Comment: Does @Ian's comment answer your question, or did you also want to know why this sum is $K$?

Comment: @joriki He does not answer my question. Yep , you are right, I also want to know why sum is K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certain to take exactly one step each from $1$ to $2$ and from $3$ to $4$; that's the constant $2$. At $2$, you have a Bernoulli experiment with success probability $\frac23$ that you perform until it succeeds, and at $4$ you have a similar Bernoulli experiment with success probability $\frac35$. The expected time until a Bernoulli experiment succeeds is the reciprocal of the success probability.

Comment: Oh! Yeahhhh!! I get it! Thank you!